# Simple Auth middleware with bcrypt is not functionning on postman

Tags: node.js

I am quite new in backend, and its my first time using a middleware with nodejs. Until now, my register function and format password are functionning on postman, since when I register a new user, I find on my DB a hashed password.

however, when I want to log in with the same user, I receive my message (wrong password or mail).
my console.log(user) read properly the user profil on node, but after, it seems like bcrypt.compareSync is not functionning. id my console.log(token), returns nothing.

I surely have a problem on my generateToken function or on my login function but I cannot figure it out.

you can see below my code.

```
login (req,res){
    Users.find({mail:req.body.mail})
    .then(users =>{
        console.log(users);

        if(users.length > 0 && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.mail+req.body.password, users[0].password)){ 
            const token= generateToken(users[0]);
            console.log(token);

            res.status(200).send('operation succeed: \n' + token);
            //res.statut(200).redirect('/logged');
        }
        else{
            res.status(500).send('wrong password or mail');
        }
    })
    .catch(err =>{
            res.send(err);
    });
},
```

}

my generateToken function:

```
function generateToken(user){
const payload={
    iat:moment().unix(), 
    exp:moment().add(14,'days').unix(), 
    iss:user.mail, 
    sub:user.password 
}
return jsonwebtoken.sign(payload,'app_secret');
```

}

thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, you use `jsonwebtoken` for token generation. There is a function called `jsonwebtoken.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, [options, callback])`. Did you try it instead of `bcrypt.compareSync(...)`?

Comment: Thank you very much it works pretty well!!!!

Comment: Great!

PS. Can you mark it as answered please?

Comment: @PierreR-A, sure! i wanted to do it but I didn't find any buttons or markup tools to approve your advice. do I have to click on "Answer your Question", even if it's not my answer?